# Is it a good idea to take another cat when my current cat is a real princess?

Tags: cats, behavior, psychology, multi-pet-families, introducing-pets

I have a five-years old female cat, that is the cuddliest cat that my husband and I ever encountered. She cannot be put on the floor, she needs to be on us (shoulder, arms, back) all the day. She loves to cuddle, to lick (she washes my husband's beard three times a day) and sleep in our arms. The only time we are left alone is when she's sleeping, she goes in her box. She is able to play alone, we sometimes stimulate her with sticks and wool thread, but she has her plushies she takes everywhere and fight. She's a home cat (we're in an apartment) and neutered.

It wasn't a problem before: my husband and I both had jobs and when we were back home, she was greeting us, so it was no wonder she wanted to cuddle. But when the pandemic started to strike, my husband lost his job and is now jobless since March 2020. He is almost 24/24 at home, and the cat never leaves him. Whenever he goes outside, even if I'm here, she cries until he gets back home, it's heartbreaking.

He's looking for a new job, and I'm 100% sure that when he'll be gone from the house, the first weeks will be terrible for her (for example, when I was able to go back to work after 2 months home everyday, each morning she blocked my legs when leaving the house), and I'm scared she will fall into depression or develop anxiety. So I wanted to adopt now another kitten (or adult cat?), so she would have a companion and not be alone all day. My husband is not okay with this idea: our cat is a real princess, she gets cuddle all the time, she gets what she wants when she wants (I'm talking about items she's stealing, not treats) and seems really in love with my husband, and jealous of me: whenever I'm kissing my husband, she runs towards him and block me from getting another. He fears she will take the new inhabitant as a threat and that it would be explosive.

Does anyone had the same problem we're facing? And what would be the options if we don't take another cat? Thanks a lot for your answers.

(Maybe a last minute addition: we live in a 65 m<sup>2</sup> apartment (700 ft<sup>2</sup>), so 2 cats would fit.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell whether adopting a second cat is a good idea?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3183/how-can-i-tell-whether-adopting-a-second-cat-is-a-good-idea)

Comment: @AllisonC not exactly, I've seen the post before and the case was a little bit different from what I experience home: my cat is stimulated, but really possessive and jealous. I've never seen her behaviour with other cats, and I don't have the possibility to foster where I live (the locale HS has already too many foster parents and it can take years before being accepted). I'm also looking for suggestion to avoid her being depressed when the situation clears itself. But yeah, the post has similarities

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a lot people being out of work or working from home, many pets are used to their humans being around all day. I worry about my cat when the day comes I go back to the office. It sounds like your cat may struggle a lot, but I don’t think getting a kitten is a good risk to take because it’s just that - a risk. I don’t want to scare you out of getting a kitten since they can be wonderful additions to the family. But it’s important to look at the whole picture.

Getting a second cat is never a guaranteed friendship. There’s a chance a kitten would help occupy your cat, but maybe not. I had two cats that used to be friends, but then had a falling out and living with them increased my stress ten fold. We hope for the best, just understand there is a worst.

Here are some things to consider:

First, both you and your partner would need to be in agreement. Introducing a new kitten to the family also introduces new stress. You both need to be okay with those challenges.

Second, how well does your cat handle change? She’ll already be going through a tough time adjusting to your new working schedules. Would adding a new stressor distract or amplify? Every cat handles these things differently, and you know her the best. A princess cat could love having a new subject under her rule!

Cats are adaptable creatures. It might take her a while, but there’s a good chance that she’ll be okay. If you decide not to go the kitten route, here are some ideas to maybe help prep her for the change:

- start leaving the house more frequently. Take day trips or even a weekend trip, then spend a few days at home again to reassure her that you’ll always come back.
- when you’re gone, make sure she has lots to occupy her. Leave out her favorite toys, turn on a cat tv show, leave items that smell like you and your partner on or around her favorite spots in the house, etc.

I hope this help you make an informed decision, and best of luck!

Comment: Few days trips will be hard with the current lockdown but I get the spirit! And I didn't know cat TV shows existed, I going to get informations on that. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Totally fair point about lockdown. Paul Dinning on YouTube posts a lot of really long videos of birds and squirrels and such that cats love watching: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XOpDIGgePCM